# Trigger/Batch with two elements as key!

Tags: apex, map

Hello everybody and especially sports lovers out there!

One of our clients is actually a major sports league in France! and at the moment, we're developping a system based on salesforce to manage all the teams, matches, statistics... etc. So here's my question:

I'm creating a batch that launches every week. this batch must update a player statistics (points, red cards, subtitutions...etc) per competition. the data is taken from a custom object called "composition equipe" that has all the data related to the player and then we must put the data per player AND per competition in a new custom object called "statistique joueur competition" (joueur= player)

To furthur explain, here's a scenario:

Let's say a player Mike scores 3 points today and 4 points next week in a competition called "league". The same Mike also scores 2 points today and 3 next week in a competition called "friendly match"

In the end, we must have in our new object "statistique joueur competition" the following records: "Mike League. 7 points" and "Mike freindly match. 5 points"

so my trouble is to find the key that combines the player and the competition together. I tried nested queries but the system only allows 2 levels of queries and there are 4 levels between my objects.

Here's a quick topology of the objects in question:

Player= contact
Parent child relationships between objects: Competition -> Match -> Composition -> Composition Equipe

I hope that it's clear for everybody. if it's not, I'd be happy to explain furthur more.

I'm also new to coding by the way!

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Can you add the query that you are currently trying to  do? And also, it is not clear to me what the relationship between Player and the other objects is..?

Comment: Player is Contact. cool! So whats the relationship between Contact & composition equipe?

Comment: as a potentially useful aside, the example used throughout the excellent book `Force.com Enterprise Architecture` is all about team sports and statistics (the domain is Formula One).  This won't directly solve your question but could either validate your design or suggest improvements.

Comment: Do you need to create both new "statistique joueur competition" records in the same batch? Perhaps it would be easier to have two batches. Then you could aggregate the results for each competition  in isolation.